python в android studio
я недавно начал учиться писать приложения в Android Studio. Я написал код на python который считывает количество труб на фото с помощью YOLOv8 после чего записывает данные в csv файл, как можно запечь готовый код на питоне в android studio?

Это проблематично. Нужно либо сразу делать на kivy или beeware без android studio, либо как-то в андроид-приложение встраивать интерпретатор python, и запускать python код этим интерпретатором.

Ну и всякое распознавание не факт что на телефоне получится запустить. Возможно проще будет этот код запускать на сервере, клиент кидает фото, сервер возвращает ответ.
